# How append multiple characters to a string in C?

Tags: c, console-application

I'm attempting to create a function that will read in a string from user input by way of reading every character off of the inputted line and inserting them into a character array. I have gotten everything correct except for appending the character to the array. I can append the first character, but after that it stops appending and will only save the first character.

```
void getstr(int maxSize, char string[]){
    char item;
    int i = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < maxSize; i++) {
        scanf("%c", &item);
        if (item == 0 || item == '\n'){
            return;
        }

        string[i] = item;
        i++;
        string[i] = 0;
    }
}
```

I call this function through another one which is used for retrieving a song and the artist from the user.

```
void getSong(char song[], char artist[]){
    printf("Please enter a song: ");
    getstr(100, song);
    printf("Please enter an artist: ");
    getstr(100, artist);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Key issues:

1. You're incrementing `i` twice per loop.  Just use `[i+1]` to store the `NUL`.
2. You should loop to `i < maxSize-1` to prevent buffer overrun when storing the terminating `NUL`.

```
void getstr(int maxSize, char string[]){
    char item;
    int i = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < maxSize-1; i++) {
        scanf("%c", &item);
        if (item == 0 || item == '\n'){
            return;
        }

        string[i] = item;
        string[i+1] = 0;
    }
}
```